Average of a signal tending to a constant
I want to prove the following claim, but I am not sure about the last sentence in the proof.
Claim. Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R}_{\geq0};\mathbb{R}^n)$. Assume that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=F\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=F$.
proof. For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $T_\varepsilon>0$ such that $\|f(t)-F\|<\varepsilon$ for all $t>T_\varepsilon$, by definition of limit. Then
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau-F=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^{T_\varepsilon} (f(\tau)-F)\mathrm{d}\tau+\int_{T_\varepsilon}^t (f(\tau)-F)\mathrm{d}\tau\right)<\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{T_\varepsilon}^t \|f(\tau)-F\|\mathrm{d}\tau<\varepsilon.$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ can be made as small as desired, we proved that indeed $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t f(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau=F$.
